# I want to run plumbing in the wall. there is some framing in the way. Can I cut it out?

Tags: framing

I am putting in a double sink vanity and took the drywall down to start the plumbing.  There is a three stud corner for a closet wall on the other side of the wall, as shown in the picture.  I want to connect the sink drains and vents together in the wall cavity.  I would like to drill holes through the studs and then cut out blocks from the stud oriented 90 degrees to the wall studs in the two places where I want to pass through the pipes (near floor and 6+ inches above vanity).  All walls are non load bearing.  Will this pass inspection?

[image: Approx where I plan to cut out]

Comment: "Will it pass inspection" is too fine a question to answer as inspectors can be tricky...

Answer (score 1):

If the parallel 2x4 is just there as a nailing edge, then yes, you can notch it safely without concern.

Answer (score 0):

If you notch rather than cutting a hole, you might be required to put these stud shoes in. Might not be a bad idea even if you cut a hole in the center.
[stud shoe](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Simpson-Strong-Tie-Stud-Shoe/52015714?wmlspartner=wlpa&selectedSellerId=5227&adid=22222222227039994571&wl0=&wl1=g&wl2=c&wl3=98291137114&wl4=aud-450464696613:pla-226100332114&wl5=9026945&wl6=&wl7=&wl8=&wl9=pla&wl10=113836495&wl11=online&wl12=52015714&wl13=&veh=sem)